# Tortoise SVN doing import after export

Tags: svn, import, export, tortoisesvn

Let's assume that I've exported my local repo because I didn't want to have .svn directories in it. Then I've made changes in my exported copy and I would like to import it back to my local repo. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I find is to check out a fresh working copy and then copy recursively (drag & drop) your exported directory over the working copy directory.

You should get a working copy with the changes you made in your exported directory where you can commit them to the repository.

Comment: This is plain enough if you haven't removed anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare the working copy with the exported one, and merge back the changes from the exported working copy to the actual working copy:

- new files must be added to the WC
- deleted files must be deleted from the WC
- different files must be replaced in the WC by the ones in the exported WC.

After the merge is done, commit the WC and don't ever make changes anymore in an exported WC.

Comment: Tortoise's Check for Modifications works just as well, combined with TortoiseMerge which gets installed by default. WinMerge works OK as a diff tool, but not as a merge tool, because it doesn't do 3-way merge.

Comment: @Sander: Check for Modifications compares a working copy with a repo. The OP wants to compare a working copy to an exported working copy with modifications. How does it solve the OP's problem? And there's no 3-way merge needed here.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I thought you were doing something else. What I usually do is copy the exported directory over the working copy, and the check for modifications. Ofcourse that way you miss the stuff that was deleted from the exported directory